# implement permutate of evaluation order in C++

Tags: c++

I've some code (to set properties in a save way) with much duplication.
It reads like this:

```
if (maximum < scrollBar.getMax())
{
    if (position < scrollBar.getPos())
    {
        scrollBar.setPos(position);
        scrollBar.setPageSize(page);
        scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
    }
    else
    {
        scrollBar.setPageSize(page);
        scrollBar.setPos(position);
        scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
    }
}
else
{
    if (position < scrollBar.getPos())
    {
        scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
        scrollBar.setPos(position);
        scrollBar.setPageSize(page);
    }
    else
    {
        scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
        scrollBar.setPageSize(page);
        scrollBar.setPos(position);
    }
}
```

I have not all possible combinations but still it is quite noisy.

In this code I can reduce this to:

```
if (!(maximum < scrollBar.getMax()))
    scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
if (position < scrollBar.getPos())
    scrollBar.setPos(position);

scrollBar.setPageSize(page);

if (!(position < scrollBar.getPos()))
    scrollBar.setPos(position);
if ((maximum < scrollBar.getMax())
    scrollBar.setMax(maximum);
```

I don't really think this code is better, but for sure: it is shorter.

Is there any method to express this evaluation order permutations in C++ in a better way?
(And maybe you know some good tags for this question)

Comment: A) Unless these are distinct properties with real names in the actual code, use *arrays* such as `std::vector`. B) Define in terms of *data structure* not code. C) Why does order matter here?

Comment: These are properties of a C++Builder Vcl object. But in more general each property corresponds to a function call and I can't use function pointers (and don't want to). If I call the setters in the wrong order, they can be out of range.

Comment: I'm not sure function pointers are a factor here. I'm just asking why the order matters. What does "out of range" mean here?

Comment: @tadman: sorry the explanation of the order came as edit to the previous response

Comment: I just find it odd that if you don't call things in some special order, things break.

Comment: I'm setting Min, Max, Position and PageSize of a TScrollBar. When you set Position bigger than Max you get a exception. Just writing '0' to all of them in the right order and increasing afterwards may give display refreshs (according to docu). Furthermore a solution might be a nice tool for other cases.

Comment: It may help to use actual names here instead of indistinguishable mystery properties. When you express it that way it instantly makes sense, however in the code you've shown it's a giant mystery.

Comment: I' changed the example slightly closer to the real code. Maybe it helps others to read this.

Comment: @m2j *Is there any method to express this evaluation order permutations in C++ in a better way?* -- Do these functions `scrollBar.setPos,  scrollBar.setPageSize, scrollBar.setMax` have the same function signature?  If so, then you could set up a way to create a map, maybe `std::map<condition, std::array<std::function<void(int)>, 3>>`, where the "condition" is the test for `max` and `pos`, and the `std::array` is an array of the 3 functions you want to call for that particular test.   Then you just call those functions specfied in the array in the order they appear.

Comment: Of course the "condition" has to be orderable in some way (maybe a `std::pair`) that corresponds to the test being made, but you should get the idea.  Granted a lot of details have been left out, which is why I didn't want to make this an answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The calls are assignments to C++Builder properties. Calling the hidden setter methods directly is not possible (they're private). One could wrap the calls in lambdas and store the call operator together with the new value in a pair. That would work, as scrollBar is globally visible (sadly).